# Modify the order of the div according to the screen size, with bootstrap 4.1.1

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm making a page in bootstrap 4.1.1, I want to change the order of the div for mobile devices, with the **order class**, but I don't get it. 
In medium to large devices, the div of block 1 must first be displayed, and the div of block 2 (sidebar), next to it.
But on mobile devices, I want the div in block 2 to be displayed first, and block 1 below this one.
I'm trying with the order class, but it doesn't work for me.

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 order-xs-2 order-sm-2">Block 1</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 order-xs-1 order-sm-1">Block 2</div></div>
</div>
```

The following image shows what I want.
[For large resolutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5AIf.png)
[For Small devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeZk3.png)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have the exact right idea. The thing to remember about Bootstrap 4 is that it is mobile-first (*unlike* Bootstrap 3). Therefor, when you add the class `order-xs-2`, you're *also* swapping the order for every viewport size above it -- including both medium and large viewports.

To correct this, simply also add `order-md-1` to your first element and `order-md-2` to your second element:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 order-xs-2 order-sm-2 order-md-1">Block 1</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 order-xs-1 order-sm-1 order-md-2">Block 2</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I'm testing it and it doesn't work, it always shows me block 1 above 2. You can see it in "Run Code Snippet"

Comment: In my snippet about, block 2 is above block 1 when they two stack (`xs or sm`). When they sit next to each other (`md`, block 1 is on the left).

Comment: Thanks you. I have copied the code on my page, and I don't see it work.
And when I click on "Expanded Snippet", and I adjust its resolution I don't see it work either. What could it be?